# I require converting this for loop into a recursion function

Tags: python, for-loop, recursion

```
rate, cashflows = 0.05,[-1100,300,450,800]

def npv_for_loop(rate,cashflows):
  NPV=0
  for i in range(len(cashflows)):
    NPV+=cashflows[i]/(1+rate)**i
    print(round(NPV,3))
```

i generally have no idea how a recursion works and would really appreciate if anybody can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recursion function is a function calling itself. It works by changing the parameters each time it calls itself until some condition accruing and then it returns. When the function hit the return value it goes back to the last line called it and continue to execute from that line, just like main function calling other. When its done executing, or hit a return, it goes back to the last line called it and continues.. so on until the function ends and returns to main.

```
rate, cashflows = 0.05,[-1100,300,450,800]

def npv_for_loop(rate,cashflows):
  NPV=0
  npv_rec(rate, cashflows, NPV)
    
def npv_rec(rate, cashflows, npv, i=0):
    if len(cashflows) == i:
        return
    npv+=cashflows[i]/(1+rate)**i
    print(round(npv,3))
    npv_rec(rate, cashflows, npv, i + 1)
    
npv_for_loop(rate, cashflows)
```